# How to get systemd to wait until zfs rollback is complete

Tags: systemd, zfs

I'm attempting to write a systemd service file that will call a script to rollback a zfs dataset at startup and at shutdown.  The startup part is working great, but I keep getting kernel panics on the shutdown process.

[image]

I think that systemd is going ahead and shutting down something important before zfs can complete the rollback.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is my current service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Public Rollback Service
After=zfs.target
Requires=zfs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/public_rollback.sh
RemainAfterExit=True
ExecStop=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/public_rollback.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script that it is calling is just:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 if zfs rollback $(zfs list -H -o name -t snapshot -r tank/public | tail -1); then
     exit 0
 else
     echo "Could not rollback public dataset! Aborting." 1>&2
     exit 1
 fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like I was wrong about where the trouble was.  Upon examining the logs, I was attempting to rollback the dataset while it was still busy (I'm assuming with the logoff procedure somehow).

I added an additional `ExecStop=/bin/sleep 1` command before the main ExecStop command giving things time to be ready to be rolled back and I haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use two services: one for startup and one for shutdown. The one you have (minus the `ExecStop` directive) for startup. And something like this to trigger the script prior to shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=Public Rollback Shutdown Service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/public_rollback.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it out, but I'm still getting the error.  I added a screenshot of the error in my original post.